# List view populating previous selected options while reusing rows

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I am using list view with cursor adapter , each list view row has four clickable options once user clicks any of these items I am highlighting correct options with green color and if user selected wrong option then selected one  in red color.

Now when I scrolls the list view it is highlighting the other row with green and red even I have not selected those options.

I know the problem is when list view reusing rows then it is happening but how to avoid them, Can any body please suggest me.

below is the code for reference

```
public class RoundsListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


    private String mOptionOne = "option_1";
    private String mOptionTwo = "option_2";
    private String mOptionThree = "option_3";
    private String mOptionFour = "option_4";

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflator;
    private Context mContext;


    public RoundsListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoQuery,int windowHeight, int windowWidth) {
        super(context, c,autoQuery);
        mLayoutInflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View customView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.talk_row_list,null);
        return customView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

        final  CustomButtonFlat option_1 = (CustomButtonFlat)view.findViewById(R.id.talks_answerA);
        View option_1SepartorView = view.findViewById(R.id.talks_answerA_seprator);
        final  CustomButtonFlat option_2 = (CustomButtonFlat)view.findViewById(R.id.talks_answerB);
        View option_2SepartorView = view.findViewById(R.id.talks_answerB_seprator);
        final  CustomButtonFlat option_3 = (CustomButtonFlat)view.findViewById(R.id.talks_answerC);
        View option_3SepartorView = view.findViewById(R.id.talks_answerC_seprator);
        final CustomButtonFlat option_4 = (CustomButtonFlat)view.findViewById(R.id.talks_answerD);
        final ImageView talksThankImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.talks_thank_image);
        final TextView talksNoOfThanks = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.talks_no_of_thanks);


        String optionA = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_1));
        String optionB = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_2));
        String optionC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_3));
        String optionD = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_4));
        if(optionA == null || optionA.length()<=0){
            option_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            option_1SepartorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            option_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            option_1SepartorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            option_1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_1)));
        }

        if(optionB == null || optionB.length()<=0){
            option_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            option_2SepartorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            option_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            option_2SepartorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            option_2.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_1)));
        }

        if(optionC == null || optionC.length()<=0){
            option_3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            option_3SepartorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            option_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            option_3SepartorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            option_3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_1)));
        }

        if(optionD == null || optionD.length()<=0){
            option_4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            option_4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            option_4.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_1)));
        }

        // only set these listeners if MCQ in the talks are available
        final String mcqAnswer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_ANSWER));
        Log.d(TAG," Talk mcq answer is = " + mcqAnswer);


        option_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionOne)){
                    option_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);


                }else if(mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionTwo)){
                    option_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);
                    // setting correct color for correct answer
                    Log.d(TAG, " Setting button color answer 2");

                }else if(mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionThree)){
                    option_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);
                    Log.d(TAG, " Setting button color answer 3");

                }else if(mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionFour)){
                    option_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);
                    Log.d(TAG, " Setting button color answer 4");
                }

            }
        });

        option_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionOne)) {
                    option_2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    option_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);

                } else if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionTwo)) {
                    option_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);

                } else if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionThree)) {
                    option_2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);

                } else if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionFour)) {
                    option_2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);
                }
            }
        });

        option_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionOne)) {
                    option_3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    option_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);

                } else if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionTwo)) {
                    option_3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);

                } else if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionThree)) {
                    option_3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);

                } else if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionFour)) {
                    option_3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);
                }
            }
        });

        option_4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionOne)) {
                    //mQuestion_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // setting correct color
                    option_4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    option_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);

                } else if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionTwo)) {
                    option_4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);

                } else if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionThree)) {
                    option_4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);

                } else if (mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionFour)) {
                    option_4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);
                }
            }
        });



    }






}
```

Comment: You have to initialize your view before each use. Otherwise you will the view in a state of previous usage. In `bindView` you should do: clear background for all elements, set background if user already selected the answer (for that you need to persist user selections).

Comment: Can you please help me by code please , you are suggesting very good thing.

Comment: I added a sample code. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

When an item is selected you should save it to your DB. The state of each row, Whether it is checked or not should be set by the `BindView` depending upon the data from the db

Comment: Nice idea , any other way which u can suggest

Comment: Actually it is just for playing without any record so thats why I am not saving these into data base

Comment: just make an an array inside adapter that save your selected answers. set the item according to that array.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code. This code is indication, it will not compile but should show you the idea. Idea is:

> You have to initialize your view before each use. Otherwise you will
>   the view in a state of previous usage. In bindView you should do:
>   clear background for all elements, set background if user already
>   selected the answer (for that you need to persist user selections).

Sample code. I deleted some parts of your code to keep it shorter.

```
public class RoundsListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


    private String mOptionOne = "option_1";
    private String mOptionTwo = "option_2";
    private String mOptionThree = "option_3";
    private String mOptionFour = "option_4";

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflator;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mAnswers;


    public RoundsListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoQuery,int windowHeight, int windowWidth) {
        super(context, c,autoQuery);
        mLayoutInflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //init array with answer. need to do the same or similar in swapCursor
        mAnswers = new String[c.getCount()];

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View customView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.talk_row_list,null);
        return customView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

        final  CustomButtonFlat option_1 = (CustomButtonFlat)view.findViewById(R.id.talks_answerA);
        ...

        //Define current position
        final currentPosition = cursor.getPosition();

        String optionA = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_1));
        ...

        //reset background color and background resources
        option_1.setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_COLOR_HERE);
        option_1.setBackgroundResource(DEFAULT_RESOURCE_HERE_OR_ZERO)
        ...
        //same for other "option_X"
        option_4.setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_COLOR_HERE);
        option_4.setBackgroundResource(DEFAULT_RESOURCE_HERE_OR_ZERO)

        if(optionA == null || optionA.length()<=0){
            option_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            option_1SepartorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            option_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            option_1SepartorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            option_1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_OPTION_1)));
        }

        ...

        // only set these listeners if MCQ in the talks are available
        final String mcqAnswer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TalkTable.TALK_ANSWER));
        Log.d(TAG," Talk mcq answer is = " + mcqAnswer);


        //init color and background for already answered questions
        if (mcqAnswer.equals(mOptionOne){
            if (mcqAnswer.equals(mAnswers[currenPosition])){
                option_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);
            } else {
                option_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);
            }
        } if (mcqAnswer.equals(mOptionTwo)){
            //the same but for optionTwo
        }
        ...
        //add same conditions for each option


        option_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //save choice. For others it will be mOptionTwo, mOptionThree, mOptionFour
                mAnswers[currenPosition] = mOptionOne;

                if(mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionOne)){
                    option_1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);


                }else if(mcqAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(mOptionTwo)){
                    option_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // settings wrong color
                    option_2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.correctMCQAnswer);
                    // setting correct color for correct answer
                    Log.d(TAG, " Setting button color answer 2");

                }else 
                ...
            }
        });

        ...
        //Other listeners



    }
}
```